# NoCommerce 3.80 External Login Plugins

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, nopcommerce-3.80, certbot-external-auth

I am new to NopCommerce as well as C# MVC. I am working on NopCommerce 3.80.

As per Instructions I downloaded Google+ Plugin from [NopCommerce Official site](http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/2179/google-external-authentication.aspx) and Installed it and also configured it.

But when i click on Login with google button, it shows an error of

> Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

[image]

Can anybody help me to solve this ?

And another Question is do I have to create a Class Library for the External Authentication as like Facebook(Inbuilt Plugin) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

**I haven't given correct callback URL that's why it's showing redirect_uri_mismatch error.
the URL I added is**

- > ***"localhost:15536/plugins/externalauthGoogle/logincallback/"***

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URI that you entered in Google developer console must exactly match the location you are trying to authenticate from this includes the port number I can see in your message.

I don't know enough about nop to tell you if you could use the Google .net client library for your application.

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you for your help. When I try to insert the URL it shows that the URL doesn't contain any " path or \ " . So I have to write only the port number nothing else. 

Can you give me more information about Google .Net api ? (I am new to .Net)